# APKTool error ricompiling apk

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiling, apktool

I' m trying to modify the application's graphic. So when I decompile the apk using apktool  with `apktool d myapp.apk`everything goes well. I can see the resources and the smali folders so it's perfect. So I can modify the colour code that I need to change.

When I try to build back the application using `apktool b myapkfolder` no errors are displayed from apktool. But when I try to install it on my phone it says "Parse error there has been a problem for analysing the packet". So I though it use my fault modifying something wrong in the application so I tried to decompile the apk and then recompile it without touching anything in the apk folder. What I can see is that the original apk size is 5.78MB and the recompiled one is 5.77MB (and I didn't touch anything literally) and when I try to install it, the phone gives me back the same error "Parse error there has been a problem for analysing the packet".

So I can't figure out what the problem is. I thought the problem was related to code obfuscation but I' m note sure. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: My best advice is: Call an **attorney**. You'll have **legal** annoyances.

Comment: The application is mine but I m not at home and I don't have my projext.. everything is legal.. don't worry

Comment: **If** the app was **yours**, you would have the **source code**. No need to `reverse engineer your own app`!

Comment: As Said I don't have my project.. Ergo there is no source code.

Comment: So, it's **not yours**. Ergo, this is a **robbery**.

Comment: You are right sorry.. but it does not seem respectful even accuse me of being a thief . If I tell you that the application is mine and I lost my project simply believe me . The thread isn't created to determine what is legal and what is not. I know what I can do and what I can not do . That's all..

Comment: You never said you lost your own code. And it's hard to believe that a programmer hasn't **at least** a backup copy of his apps on some pendrive or external hdd or **free** cloud storage.

Comment: If you were ME, would you believe YOU?

Comment: if I were you I would not have even raised the issue because the thread asking another, I'm not interested in other people's business this forum is to help people to solve problems, not to preach . Anyway I really lost my project and I m not at home as I wrote earlier so I can't use my PC . If you want believe ok otherwise I can't do nothing

Comment: @AlessioTrecani Check the logs using logcat. Do you find any additional errors/warnings?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi this is a perfectly valid question. Op has not expressed any interest in attempting to upload the modified app to the app store nor is this illegal. If anything, OP should learn to use google because there are countless number of guides on how to do this exact thing.

Comment: @AlessioTrecani http://androidforums.com/threads/guide-how-to-properly-decompile-and-recompile-apks-with-apktool.520917/ here's one such guide on how to do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but this question is a bit old.. Now I work in a reverse team.. thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Well If you have lost you project and you want to import it to eclipse then you can use this link: [click here](http://blog.inyourbits.com/2012/11/extending-existing-android-applications.html)

And Yes ill tell you your question is valid ( and by the way there's nothing to do legal or illegal here as this forum is to clear your doubts )

The link will have two parts on importing your decompiled files and yes if you are unsuccessful in decompiling then this link will help you out [click here](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk)

And yes you try these things anywhere..( and personally you MUST KEEP A BACKUP ON CLOUD STORAGE , WHERE YOU CAN ACCESS IT FROM ANYWHERE )